# How can a variable be used during the setting of an Entity Framework entity (versus hardcoding)?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-3.1

This works:

```
string sql = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}";
var executeSQL = db.Set<MyTableContextType>().FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList();
```

But this code will be accepting requests for multiple tables (past MyTableContextType).  Rather than hardcoding MyTableContextType, I'd like to do something like this:

```
dynamic entityType = db.Model.FindEntityType(stringMyType);
string sql = $"SELECT * FROM {tableName}";
var executeSQL = db.Set<entityType>().FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList();
```

All of the above works, except the last line which gives this error:

```
'entityType' is a variable but is used like a type.
```

How can a variable be fed into db.Set<>?

If there is a better way, I am open to that too.

---

.NET Core 3.1
& EF Core 3.1

Answer (score 0):

It won't work since Generics is a compile-time concern, but type from `FindEntityType` is a runtime concern.

In your case, extracting `db.Set<MyTableContextType>().FromSqlRaw(sql).ToList()` to generic method may help.

Something like
`private TEntity SelectAll<TEntity>(string tableName) => db.Set<TEntity>().FromSqlRaw($"SELECT * FROM {tableName}").ToList();`

Alternative way to solve it - use [LINQ to SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/#:%7E:text=Entity%20Framework%20Core%20uses%20Language,classes%20to%20reference%20database%20objects.) methods instead of raw SQL in order to select the data.

Comment: Thanks, I'm actually using LINQ to SQL, but am not sure how to dynamically set table name in the SELECT portion.  That's why I moved over to using FromSqlRaw, but if there is a way to do this with LINQ to SQL I would prefer that.

Comment: You may try to use Reflection in order to find related DbSets in Context by table name dynamically. But, for me, it seems like a hack and should be avoided. Direct usage of tables (without dynamic resolution) is more robust.